How can I find valid starting positions for my puzzle game?
Here is an animation I made of how the game plays. https://i.imgur.com/KRXCOyD.mp4 It's an empty board with two tiles (T) showing how they interact with each other. There can also be walls (W) that act like the tiles but they can't be moved — they only stop the moveable tiles.
You can only move one tile at a time. When you move it, it slides until it stops. Tiles could theoretically be places anywhere on the board, but I'm trying to find what I call starting positions. In graph-theory, they create a cycle and once you get into a cycle, you can't escape. I don't want to start outside this cycle. So if I start the puzzle in an invalid state (e.i. not on starting positions) I would eventually get into a valid state, but I don't want it to ever be invalid.
For the animation, there's 28 valid starting positions. If it were just one tile, there would be only 4.
Here's how I think it could be done. Let's just focus on one for now.

Here we have a moveable tile in the top left corner and a wall on the bottom row.

From the start, I could move down or right. From down, I could only move back up. From the right, I could move down, left, and then up. From the final up position, I could move left or right but notice these are one-way.
If I number the cells of the board 1 through 25 like this:

Then the directed graph for all the starting positions would look like this:

Notice how I can reach any node from any other node. I might have to take a detour to get back to 3 but it's possible.
If I started in the middle which is a non-valid position:

The graph ends up looking like this:

Here, 11, 13, and 15 are invalid starting positions. It's difficult to see, but if you start on any of them and then move to a valid position, you can never get back to an invalid position.
I'm trying to make an algorithm that can get all the valid starting positions. Here's how I think I could do it. I'm hoping somebody can tell me if I'm right or wrong, or if there's a better way. I'd start with a depth-first or breadth-first search. This could generate a list of candidates. Then for each cell that wasn't visited, do another search until I have a list of lists of candidates. Then I would union all the lists together. Maybe that would work, I'm not sure.
I don't know if I could use something like Tarjan's Algorithm for strongly connected components or if I just need to cycle detection algorithm.
I'm thinking my solution might not work, because it's possible to have more than 1 list of valid starting positions. Consider the following:

Each tile forms their own cycle. For these examples, I'm only considering 1 or 2 tiles, but in reality, there can be between 1 and empty cells - 1 tiles. There needs to be at least one in order to move to. And I understand these graphs can get quiet large.

Also, if it would be better to ask this question on cs.stackexchange or math.stackexchange, just let me know and I'll move it.

If I'm understanding correctly, I think what you're looking for is equivalent to identifying the strongly connected components in the graph of puzzle states, contracting each S.C.C. to a single vertex to get a directed acyclic graph of such components, then finding the sink vertices of that condensed graph. Those sinks correspond to the strongly connected components that contain your valid starting positions: mutually-reachable states with no escape routes from that set. Does that sound right?

After you condensed the graph, you end up with a directed acyclic graph, right? In my first example, you can move from 3 to 5 to 25 to 23 back to 3 which is a cycle, so I'm thinking that won't work. Unless I'm not understanding you correctly. I'll admit my graph theory is not the best.

The condensation step turns 3 5 25 and 23 (and 1 and 21) into a single vertex, so it's no longer a cycle in the condensed graph. That's what makes the condensed version a DAG. See the image I linked from Wikipedia: while there are cycles in the original graph (in blue/black), the condensed graph (in yellow) is a DAG, where each yellow bubble maps to a strongly connected component from the original graph.

I see, so if what you're saying is true, then I'm only looking for this vertex. Is there a way to go from this vertex to the vertices I'm talking about (1, 3, 5, 21, 23, 25). Or is it like a data structure that contains it? If the start position graph ends up containing two or more separate cycles (last example), would this correspond to two vertices in the condensed graph or as two separate DAGs?

Each strongly connected component (which may contain multiple intersecting cycles) gets reduced to a single vertex in the condensed graph. You can get back to the vertices of the original graph by just doing some book-keeping when you apply the condensation step. If there are multiple strongly connected components with no outflows, they will each become a separate sink vertex in the condensed DAG, so you can count the sinks to detect how many disjoint sets of valid starting positions you have.

This is just gut feel - I haven't really gone through it in great depth, but the concept of reducing the graph feels like it would work well for one (or a small number of movable tiles) but as the number of tiles increases I suspect that you would need to treat this problem more like chess where you are evaluating board positions rather than looking at the move sequences directly.

5 tiles on a 25-square board (so 20% occupancy) yields 53130 states to check in the worst case, which is reasonably small if you're precomputing this. I'd only really worry about it if you were scaling up to larger boards or trying to do it at runtime on a mobile platform. I got nerdsniped and built a program that uses the algorithm above, but it needs some debugging before I can post it as a vetted answer.

I got pretty nerdsniped by this, and cooked up some Unity-style C# code to find these valid starting states.
I'm using a "bitboard" strategy to represent puzzle states. An unsigned long integer has 64 bits, which I interpret as the cells in an 8x8 chessboard grid, indexed like so:















7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0


15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8


23
22
21
20
19
18
17
16


31
30
29
28
27
26
25
24


39
39
37
36
35
34
33
32


47
46
45
44
43
42
41
40


55
54
53
52
51
50
49
48


63
62
61
60
59
58
57
56



So 1 bit in index 17 (1 << 17 = 65536) represents a tile in the third row from the top, second column from the right.
I know this indexing is flipped left to right from the version shown in the question, but since I'm going to be using bit shifts to move the tiles around, I wanted a right shift like tile >> 1 (making the number smaller) to mean the tile is moving to the right.
Sliding a tile right n spaces is then tile >> n. Left is tile << n. Up is tile << (n * 8) and down is tile >> (n * 8).
I use one bitboard to represent the positions of the walls (filling any unused rows/columns when working with a board smaller than this 8x8 max), and another to represent the positions of the sliding tiles in a given puzzle state.
Then I run a modified version of Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm:

I start with a state with all the sliding tiles clustered to the right of the top row, then iterate over all permutations with the same number of set bits that don't overlap with the walls (easy to check with a bitwise AND).

For each valid pattern of tiles I haven't already explored, I run a depth-first search of all puzzle states reachable from that one, numbering the states as they're discovered and keeping track of the lowest-numbered state reachable from each subtree of the search. This lets us detect when a subtree forms a strongly connected component, so we can prune it from our stack.

As I explore each state, I also keep track of whether I've found any outgoing edges that lead to already-discovered strongly connected components - that's the hasOutflow flag.
I skip storing any components that have outflow, so we only keep the "terminal components": groups of potential starting / target states where all states will always be mutually reachable, and there's no way to take a "wrong turn" and become unable to get back to your starting state or to the target state.


My code looks like this - I've elided getter/setter methods for setting the wall positions / reading out the starting positions found:
public class SlidingTileSearch {

    public struct StateInfo {
        // Bitboard representing where the movable tiles are.
        public ulong bitmask;

        // Index of the earliest-discovered state reachable
        // from this one.
        public int lowestReachableIndex;

        // Tracks whether this state could still be part
        // of an undiscovered strongly connected component.
        public bool isOnStack;

        // Tracks whether this state can reach some other
        // already-discovered strongly connected component.
        public bool hasOutflow;
    }



    // Number of possible arrangements of 2 tiles on an 8x8 board.
    // Pre-sizing the containers to a generous capacity reduces
    // memory allocations in the middle of the algorithm.
    const int CAPACITY = 32 * 63;

    // Maps a bitboard state to its index in the order it was discovered.
    Dictionary<ulong, int> stateIndex = new(CAPACITY);

    // State info structure for each discovered state, in discovery order.
    List<StateInfo> stateInfo = new(CAPACITY);

    // Stack of states in the current depth-first search invocation,
    // which are not yet assigned to a strongly connected component.
    Stack<int> unassignedStates = new();

    // List of valid sets of starting/target puzzle state bitboards.
    // Each inner list is one cluster of mutually-reachable states.
    List<List<ulong>> startingStates = new();

    // Helper stack used for temporarily storing the child states
    // reachable from a given parent state.
    Stack<ulong> reachable = new();

    // Bitboard representing the locations of stationary walls.
    ulong walls;

    public int FindValidStartingPoints(int tileCount) {
        // Reset all our data structures from any previous search.
        stateIndex.Clear();        
        stateInfo.Clear();
        startingStates.Clear();
        reachable.Clear();

        // First state to check has all tiles clustered in top-right,
        // final state to check has all tiles clustered in bottom-left.
        ulong candidate = 0;
        ulong last = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tileCount; i++) {
            candidate |= 1ul << i;
            last |= 1ul << (63-i);
        }

        // Loop over all possible arrangements of tileCount movable tiles.
        while(true) {
            // Skip states that have a tile out of bounds or overlapping a wall.
            if ((candidate & walls) == 0) {
                // If we haven't already discovered this puzzle state,
                // run a new depth-first search from here.
                if (!stateIndex.ContainsKey(candidate)) {
                    StrongConnect(candidate);
                }
            }
            // Stop after the final bit pattern.
            if (candidate == last) break;
            candidate = Next(candidate);
        }

        // Report on our findings.
        Debug.Log($"Checked {stateInfo.Count} possible puzzle states and found {startingStates.Count} {(startingStates.Count == 1 ? "cluster" : "clusters")} of starting states:");
        int totalStateCount = 0;
        foreach(var group in startingStates) {
            string stateInfo = "";
            foreach(var state in group) {
                totalStateCount++;
                stateInfo += "\n";
                var remaining = state;
                while(remaining != 0) {                    
                    ExtractLowestBit(ref remaining, out int x, out int y);
                    stateInfo += $"({x}, {y}) ";
                }
            }
            Debug.Log($"- set of {group.Count} states: {stateInfo}");
        }

        return totalStateCount;
    }

    // Recursive depth-first search step. Checks a given puzzle states and the
    // subtree of undiscovered puzzle states reachable from it.
    // Returns the index of this state in discovery order (starting at zero).
    int StrongConnect(ulong state) {
        // Initialize our info for this state and mark it as discovered.
        var index = stateInfo.Count;
        var info = new StateInfo() {
            bitmask = state,
            lowestReachableIndex = index,
            isOnStack = true
        };
        stateInfo.Add(info);
        stateIndex.Add(state, index);
        unassignedStates.Push(index);

        // Find all reachable child states.
        int notMyChildren = reachable.Count;
        FindReachableChildren(state);

        // Iterate over those reachable child states.
        while(reachable.Count > notMyChildren) {
            var child = reachable.Pop();
            StateInfo childInfo;

            // Check if we've already discovered this state.
            if (stateIndex.TryGetValue(child, out var childIndex)) {
                childInfo = stateInfo[childIndex];
                if (childInfo.isOnStack) {
                    // Already-discovered state not yet assigned to a component,
                    // meaning this is a "back-edge" into the current component.
                    info.lowestReachableIndex = Mathf.Min(info.lowestReachableIndex, childIndex);
                } else {
                    // Already-discovered node not in current tree, 
                    // meaning this is a cross-edge to another component.
                    info.hasOutflow = true;
                }
            } else {
                // Undiscovered state: recurse down the tree.
                childIndex = StrongConnect(child);
                childInfo = stateInfo[childIndex];
                info.lowestReachableIndex = Mathf.Min(info.lowestReachableIndex, childInfo.lowestReachableIndex);
            }
            // Save modified info.
            info.hasOutflow |= childInfo.hasOutflow;
            stateInfo[index] = info;
        }

        // Done recursing on all reachable children.

        // Peel off a strongly-connected component if we've finished exploring one.
        if (info.lowestReachableIndex == index) {
            // I am the root of this strongly connected component. 
            // All states still on the stack are part of "my" component.           

            // If this is a terminal/sink component, save it.
            List<ulong> scc = null;
            if (!info.hasOutflow) scc = new();

            // Pop off the remaining sub-tree.
            int popIndex;
            do {
                popIndex = unassignedStates.Pop();
                var popInfo = stateInfo[popIndex];
                popInfo.isOnStack = false;
                popInfo.hasOutflow = true;
                stateInfo[popIndex] = popInfo;
                scc?.Add(popInfo.bitmask);
                
            } while (popIndex != index);

            if (scc != null) startingStates.Add(scc);
        } else {
            // This strongly connected component has its root somewhere
            // earlier in the stack. I'll hang out on the stack
            // until we rewind to that root, and it will pop me off.
        }

        return index;
    }

    // Uses bitshifts to find all valid puzzle moves that can be made
    // from a given state of sliding tile positions.
    void FindReachableChildren(ulong state) {
        // Iterate over each tile that can slide, and try sliding it in each direction.
        ulong remainingToSlide = state;
        while (remainingToSlide != 0) {
            ulong oldBit = ExtractLowestBit(ref remainingToSlide, out int x, out int y);    

            // State of all tiles *other* than this one we're going to try moving.
            ulong otherState = state ^ oldBit;
            // State of anything that could stop this tile in its slide.
            ulong obstacles = walls | otherState;

            ulong moved = 0;
            int i;

            // Scan right.
            int limit = x + 1;
            for (i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
                moved = oldBit >> i;
                if ((moved & obstacles) != 0) break;
            }
            if (i > 1) {
                i--;
                reachable.Push(otherState | (oldBit >> i));
            }

            // Scan left.
            limit = 8-x;
            for (i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
                moved = oldBit << i;
                if ((moved & obstacles) != 0) break;
            }
            if (i > 1) {
                i--;
                reachable.Push(otherState | (oldBit << i));
            }

            // Scan up.
            limit = (y + 1) * 8;
            for (i = 8; i < limit; i +=8) {
                moved = oldBit >> i;
                if ((moved & obstacles) != 0) break;
            }
            if (i > 8) {
                i -= 8;
                reachable.Push(otherState | (oldBit >> i));
            }

            // Scan down.
            limit = (8 - y) * 8;
            for (i = 8; i < limit; i +=8) {
                moved = oldBit << i;
                if ((moved & obstacles) != 0) break;
            }
            if (i > 8) {
                i -= 8;
                reachable.Push(otherState | (oldBit << i));
            }            
        }
    }

    // Pops the lowest bit out of the state bitboard into its own bitboard,
    // and reports its x & y coordinates, measured from the top-right corner.
    ulong ExtractLowestBit(ref ulong state, out int x, out int y) {
        var zeros = math.tzcnt(state);        
        x = zeros & 7;
        y = zeros >> 3;
        var bit = 1ul << zeros;
        state ^= bit;
        return bit;
    }


    // Next bit permutation code from
    // https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation
    ulong Next(ulong state) {
        long v = (long)state;
        long t = v | (v - 1); // t gets v's least significant 0 bits set to 1
        // Next set to 1 the most significant bit to change, 
        // set to 0 the least significant ones, and add the necessary 1 bits.
        long w = (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (math.tzcnt(v) + 1));  
        return (ulong)w;
    }
}

As an example, we could test it on the example shown in the question with a wall on the top and bottom rows and two movable tiles, like so:
    void Test() {
        
        walls
        = 0xE4ul        // ###__#__
        | 0xE0ul << 8   // ###_____
        | 0xE0ul << 16  // ###_____
        | 0xE0ul << 24  // ###_____
        | 0xE4ul << 32  // ###__#__
        | 0xFFul << 40  // ########
        | 0xFFul << 48  // ########
        | 0xFFul << 56; // ########
        
        FindValidStartingPoints(2);
    }

This takes less than 4 milliseconds to run on my laptop, and reports back:

Checked 253 possible puzzle states and found 1 cluster of starting states:

set of 16 states: 
(1, 4) (3, 4)  
(1, 4) (4, 4)  
(0, 4) (4, 4)  
(4, 0) (0, 4)  
(4, 0) (1, 4)  
(1, 0) (4, 0)  
(1, 0) (4, 4)  
(1, 0) (3, 4)  
(1, 0) (3, 0)  
(3, 0) (1, 4)  
(3, 0) (0, 4)  
(0, 4) (3, 4)  
(0, 0) (3, 4)  
(0, 0) (3, 0)  
(0, 0) (4, 0)  
(0, 0) (4, 4)  


This corresponds to all possible combinations of one tile in a corner on the left half of the map, and the other in a corner on the right half of the map.
Try it with 1 tile, and it will find two possible clusters of starting states: one on the left, and one on the right.

It works fine for 2 and 3 tiles, but I'm getting a stack overflow at 4 tiles.

An unfortunate downside to using recursion to keep this example code simple. The solution is to replace the recursive function calls with iteration and your own stack variable, rather than using the function call stack. There are only 12 650 possible 4-tile arrangements, and a 5x5 board maxes out at 5.2 million, so it's still feasible to use this algorithm on even old PCs with this change. I'm afraid I've already sunk all the time I can into this answer though, so I'll have to leave that upgrade as an exercise for the reader.

No problem, you've done a lot already. Thanks for your help @DMGregory. I was able to get an iteration version working.

Great work! Want to share that version as your own answer? It might help others working on similar problems.

Actually, I was wrong. I thought I had an iterative version, but after further testing, it doesn't work in all cases.

An alternative way to generate a valid start state would be to start with the target state and "scramble" the board with reverse moves - where a reverse move is the opposite of a valid forward move, so the code generates all states that are one move before the current state and picks one at random.
I understand that this won't always find a fun/difficult state for the player to start with so you might want to manually do the first few reverse moves to get the state somewhere near where you want it then let the computer scramble the manual state randomly with a couple of additional moves on each play through.
I would recommend building yourself a UI that will allow you to quickly pick reverse moves to save yourself time when creating a bunch of levels.

This is a good general strategy for many puzzle games, but not necessarily ideal for this particular one. Only a small number of target states fulfil the criteria described in the question, so "start with the target state" leaves the hard part unanswered. Specifically, we want both the starting state and the target state to be part of a cluster of states that are all mutually reachable and there's no way to make a "wrong turn" that can't be undone. The approach in this answer has the potential to choose starting states that can reach the target, but also permit these unrecoverable wrong turns.
